# Remove Sticky GroupHeader from LongListSelector?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there a way to remove Sticky GroupHeader property from a LongListSelector? I need to see all groups open like a regular listing pushing the footer down.

Comment: +1, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0a2c44ba-3f62-4a9c-8a27-f0e03b79c0db/remove-sticky-header-from-windows-phone-8-longlistselector?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Yes, I saw that one, but no answer is given for that one. Hope I will get one here.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the `IsGroupingEnabled` property within your `longlistselector` and make the `LayoutMode` as `list`.

```
 <phone:LongListSelector 
 IsGroupingEnabled="False"
 LayoutMode="List" />
```

Comment: But I want to see the group headers.

Comment: @DamlaKutluoğlu How come? Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I want to create a page with its header, body and footer, and the body of the page will only contain my list. I want the height of the body to get bigger if my list is longer. As a usual web page i want this page be to scrolled entirely. But here in this case only list is scrolling and headers of the list groups sticks at top.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set grouping header. Try to set `IsGroupingEnabled` to **false**.

See this for more information : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.isgroupingenabled%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/05/23/windows-phone-8-xaml-longlistselector.aspx

Comment: I want to see the group header, I need the body part of my page (which only contains my list) to exdend as long as the list size, like a normal html page, I dont want to see the footer of the page and list scrolling in the body part.